# Custom view appears blank in AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

Why is that my custom view doesn't appear within my `AlertDialog` whenever I try to use it for my `RecyclerView` adapter? I created the necessary adapters and classes, but for some reason I'm not seeing any of my custom layout as expected.

**expected result**

[image]

**current result**

[image]

**adapter**

```
class MyRVAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<Facility>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterFacilities.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return facilitiesList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Hide LinearLayout containing TextViews on fragment load
        holder.mLLTextViews.visibility = View.GONE

        val item = facilitiesList[position]

        holder.myButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Initialize a new instance of AlertDialog
            val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(holder.itemView.context)

            // Set the alert dialog title
            builder.setTitle("Dialog title")

            // Set the alert dialog icon
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp)

            // Set the alert dialog view
            builder.setView(R.layout.fragment_dialog)

            // Find TabLayout and ViewPager views
            val tabLayout: TabLayout = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_dialog_tabs) as TabLayout
            val viewPager: ViewPager = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_dialog_viewPager) as ViewPager

            // Set classes per tab, set tab names
            val adapter = CustomAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())
            adapter.addFragment("Boy",CustomFragment.createInstance("John"));
            adapter.addFragment("Girl",CustomFragment.createInstance("Stacy"));
            adapter.addFragment("Robot", CustomFragment.createInstance("Aeon"));
            viewPager.adapter = adapter
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

            // Set TabLayout text colour
            // Set TabLayout indicator colour
            tabLayout.setTabTextColors(holder.itemView.resources.getColor(R.color.piccadilly, null), holder.itemView.resources.getColor(R.color.grey, null))
            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(holder.itemView.resources.getColor(R.color.grey, null))


            // Display a positive button on alert dialog
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok){ dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss()}

            // Finally, make the alert dialog using 'builder'
            val dialog: android.app.AlertDialog = builder.create()

            // Display the alert dialog on app interface
            dialog.show()
        }
     }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_cv, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    // button view holder
    class ViewHolder (itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val myBtn = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.my_btn)!!
    }
}
```

**CustomFragment class**

```
class CustomFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private var mText = ""

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false)
        (v.findViewById(R.id.textView_sample) as TextView).text = mText
        return v
    }

    companion object {
        fun createInstance(txt: String): CustomFragment {
            val fragment = CustomFragment()
            fragment.mText = txt
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter class**

```
class CustomAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    private var mFragmentCollection: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
    private var mTitleCollection: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    fun addFragment(title: String, fragment: Fragment) {
        mTitleCollection.add(title)
        mFragmentCollection.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mTitleCollection[position]
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentCollection[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentCollection.size
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's based on the context inflating the view. Try modifying it just slightly. Pass your activity into the recyclerview and save an instance of it there. This is strictly for a test purposes.

Like so:

```
class MyRVAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<Facility>, val myActivity: Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterFacilities.ViewHolder>() {
```

I'm guessing your issue is here:

```
val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(holder.itemView.context)
```

Try doing this.

```
val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity)
val view = myActivity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null)
```

If that works for you, then it is your inflation process that needs the Activity context rather than your adapter context.

Then it's up to you if you want to retain your activity context in the adapter or if you are ok handling the dialog inflation outside of the adapter.

My personal preference is to make a callback for handling click events that passes out the item and/or index and allow the owning activity to do any inflating. That would be my recommendation, but for testing purposes you can do above and make the call yourself.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Where did you get `myActivity` from?

Comment: My first comment :). I said "modify it slightly" pass your activity into the recycler view. Here i will update to help you, I assumed you made the recycler view

Comment: Also please don't name it myActivity lol, that was for example purposes

Comment: The RecyclerView was alerdy made + I'm using a `Fragment` (not `Activity`) to show my `RecyclerView`.

Comment: What do I replace `mySavedActivity` with?

Comment: I still get this error: `Unresolved reference: getChildFragmentManager`

Comment: MacaronLover, what is your level of Android experience? I need to know so I don't over explain. Your error is because you are attempting to get something again from the wrong context. try myActivity.getChildFragmentManager() but also it matters if you are using support fragments and support activity or if you are using standard activity and fragment as you will need the get support child fragment manager call if you are working with support activity.

Comment: My level is between beginner & intermediate. I'm not using support fragments, I'm using AndroidX.

Comment: ok great, so you should understand context and fragment manager. If you are not getting a fragment manager that means you are not trying to get it from an inappropriate context, so use the activity like i showed you above and let me know if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Isn't `mySavedActivity` supposed to be `myActivity`?

Comment: I think you need to update your shared code as now I have no idea what you are asking now lol. I wrote you an example adapter that has a variable called myActivity. If you renamed that to mySavedActivity that is fine.

Comment: I didn't rename it to that

Comment: Great, so what are you asking then?

Comment: I applied your suggestions but the eroor still remains. See my latest screenshot

Comment: Macaron what does your activity extend? Is it a FragmentActivity or an AppCompatActivity. If you are adding this dialog into a fragment then you can use getChildFragmentManager if you are in a correct type of Activity. Otherwise if you are adding to an activity then you should use getSupportFragmentManager or getFragmentManager depending on your activity type and dialog type.